# Ambiguous call when inheriting multiple times from generic base class

Tags: c++, stl, multiple-inheritance, ambiguous, ambiguity

I want to clone a data structure containing `std::list`s of several types and simultaneously move some iterators to point to the new `std::list`'s elements. For this, I created a generic type `Translate<T>` represents the mapping from `std::list<T>::iterator`s in the old list to those in the new list. I then have a new class inherit from `Translate<T>` for all the needed types `T` of my data structure.

Here's a simplified example (using just an identity function):

```
#include <list>

struct T1 {};
struct T2 {};

template<typename T>
class Translate {
    public:
    typename std::list<T>::iterator operator()(typename std::list<T>::iterator x) {
        return x; // more complex in the real world, but doesn't matter here
    }
};

int main() {
    std::list<T1> l1{};
    std::list<T2> l2{};

    class : public Translate<T1>, public Translate<T2> {} tr;
    tr(l1.begin());
}
```

This gives me the following compiler error:

```
mwe.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
mwe.cpp:19:15: error: request for member ‘operator()’ is ambiguous
  tr(l1.begin());
               ^
mwe.cpp:9:34: note: candidates are: ‘typename std::__cxx11::list<T>::iterator Translate<T>::operator()(typename std::__cxx11::list<T>::iterator) [with T = T2; typename std::__cxx11::list<T>::iterator = std::_List_iterator<T2>]’
  typename std::list<T>::iterator operator()(typename std::list<T>::iterator x) {
                                  ^~~~~~~~
mwe.cpp:9:34: note:                 ‘typename std::__cxx11::list<T>::iterator Translate<T>::operator()(typename std::__cxx11::list<T>::iterator) [with T = T1; typename std::__cxx11::list<T>::iterator = std::_List_iterator<T1>]’
```

In what way is the call ambiguous? The `std::list<T>::iterator`s are not convertible to each other.

**It works** if I manually copy the implementation for each `T` into the child class, but that's exactly what is trying to be avoided when using generics and inheritance.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  Both Clang and MSVS compile this code.  I could only get it to fail with GCC.  Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: `g++ 8.3.0`. You're right, it compiles fine with clang, I didn't even think about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is ill-formed. If the `operator()` is not available in the derived class, then name lookup only considers the base class if there is *exactly* one base class. If there are multiple base classes, then *none* of the base classes are considered in name lookup.

As you've mentioned, you can copy the implementations of `operator()` into the derived class, and that works, but you can also bring both of the `operator()` names into the derived class with a `using` directive, like this:

```
class : public Translate<T1>, public Translate<T2> {
  public:
    using Translate<T1>::operator();
    using Translate<T2>::operator();
} tr;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/b5a9M7).

Comment: Doesn't [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.member.lookup#5) mean that all bases are considered?

Comment: @NathanOliver Not 100% sure, but I think [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.member.lookup#6.2) means that the merge process is ambiguous in this case. Maybe the wording also relates to templates. Perhaps this should be a language-lawyer question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, adding a `using` declaration fixes the problem. Then it might just be GCC's error message that needs work.

Is there also a way to bring all members into the derived class without needed to name every method for every superclass?

Comment: Yeah, not sure.  Overload resolution is a complicated beast.  Half the time I look at that standard section I'm surprised my head doesn't explode.

Comment: No, you have to bring every name you want manually.